# MFC/WINAPI: How to check the DVD drive is present in machine

Tags: winapi, mfc

I want to check whether the DVD writer is present or not in my machine using MFC/WinAPI.
Could anyone please help on this.

Thank

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate DVD drivers and their capabilities using [IMAPI2, IDiscRecorder2 interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365604):

> To retrieve a list of devices on the computer and their unique identifiers, call the `IDiscMaster2::get__NewEnum` method.

Then [`IDiscRecorder2::get_SupportedProfiles method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365595):

> List of MMC profiles that the device supports.

```cpp
typedef enum _IMAPI_PROFILE_TYPE { 
  IMAPI_PROFILE_TYPE_INVALID                     = 0,
  IMAPI_PROFILE_TYPE_NON_REMOVABLE_DISK          = 0x1,
  IMAPI_PROFILE_TYPE_REMOVABLE_DISK              = 0x2,
  IMAPI_PROFILE_TYPE_MO_ERASABLE                 = 0x3,
  IMAPI_PROFILE_TYPE_MO_WRITE_ONCE               = 0x4,
  IMAPI_PROFILE_TYPE_AS_MO                       = 0x5,
  IMAPI_PROFILE_TYPE_CDROM                       = 0x8,
  IMAPI_PROFILE_TYPE_CD_RECORDABLE               = 0x9,
  IMAPI_PROFILE_TYPE_CD_REWRITABLE               = 0xa,
  IMAPI_PROFILE_TYPE_DVDROM                      = 0x10,
  IMAPI_PROFILE_TYPE_DVD_DASH_RECORDABLE         = 0x11,
  IMAPI_PROFILE_TYPE_DVD_RAM                     = 0x12,
  IMAPI_PROFILE_TYPE_DVD_DASH_REWRITABLE         = 0x13,
  // (and there is more!)
```

Also, [IMAPI_FEATURE_PAGE_TYPE enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366210), which all together give you detail what the drive is capable to do (whether it can write and what exactly):

> ... defines values for the feature that are supported by the logical unit (CD and DVD device).